# What does Steam give me as a gamer?

Tags: steam

I know I can buy games in Steam, but what are the benefits of doing so over purchasing a no-DRM version of a game? What features does Steam provide to an average gamer to improve their gaming and user experience?

Comment: I think this is a legitmate question, but I can also see that it can be merged with this other question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/what-is-steam-drm?rq=1